# Using Semantic UI with React and Meteor

Tags: meteor, reactjs, semantic-ui

Is it possible to install Semantic UI through NPM and import it in to the meteor client? Hope I'm making sense here. I have been doing this with bootstrap.

1. Install Bootstrap NPM
2. import it to my main css

   @import '{}/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';

Comment: Have you tried this? Try doing just that and then come back if you have an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but then there is already an official package available in meteor (https://atmospherejs.com/semantic/ui)